# Geetest solved by 2captcha but the cookie returned by the validation call is not the cookie used by the website

Tags: web-scraping, cookies, 2captcha

I'm trying to bypass geetest on fnac.com website, I'm using 2captcha api to validate the challenge then I identified the call that return the cookie:
[https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/check?cid=..SsK8q3LhU5AW5Qu66tG2d-lhcyHMlhF1Rrii6BD7xyM7.8KPg-v~AHSSdw4qxkWiKg4t.-caU1dUfQiZLltm0cmD1dOBaB.W_AKhYQtRUOXHVOVrUKBdQXIY-C_OoT&icid=AHrlqAAAAAMAtm8aV_7j23YAU433Dw%3D%3D&ccid=null&geetest-response-challenge=63c96502b92aa3a627437ce380154a4d9h&geetest-response-validate=1a0421425f1d346814b72b3bb69e9f19&geetest-response-seccode=1a0421425f1d346814b72b3bb69e9f19%7Cjordan&hash=4BA90718940D0114F409A57DFAF6AF&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F96.0.4664.110%20Safari%2F537.36&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fnac.com%2F&parent_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fnac.com%2F&x-forwarded-for=83.141.247.15&captchaChallenge=3111270&s=3909](https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/check?cid=..SsK8q3LhU5AW5Qu66tG2d-lhcyHMlhF1Rrii6BD7xyM7.8KPg-v%7EAHSSdw4qxkWiKg4t.-caU1dUfQiZLltm0cmD1dOBaB.W_AKhYQtRUOXHVOVrUKBdQXIY-C_OoT&icid=AHrlqAAAAAMAtm8aV_7j23YAU433Dw%3D%3D&ccid=null&geetest-response-challenge=63c96502b92aa3a627437ce380154a4d9h&geetest-response-validate=1a0421425f1d346814b72b3bb69e9f19&geetest-response-seccode=1a0421425f1d346814b72b3bb69e9f19%7Cjordan&hash=4BA90718940D0114F409A57DFAF6AF&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F96.0.4664.110%20Safari%2F537.36&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fnac.com%2F&parent_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fnac.com%2F&x-forwarded-for=83.141.247.15&captchaChallenge=3111270&s=3909)

```
{"cookie":"datadome=..SsK8q3LhU5AW5Qu66tG2tILIphTBMNctAEMi_uQ6aHWLLGKiD.Bw.Pb4sCVZO_I4l-2j6QuABAgywoVHKK6MqLJuY4PfYHdYR~E9JuaW9m45WnTmeyNEa7ry2xsgsh; Max-Age=31536000; Domain=.fnac.com; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=Lax"}
```

But the cookie used in the "htttps://www.fnac.com" call is datadome=..SsK8q3LhU5AW5Qu66tG2RT-GSJSXwW0hA595c7qAgHa1X3e8MSjuxEhzX0kbf8gBD47H~9wiuBpKg7J4CLZ..YhqiRbUezJf6nI7.d7nzSWv6Q6A~rRvCPGMIBp0Bq  which is slightly different.

I spent a a lot of time digging into js code to identify which part change the cookie but I'm still not able to find the trick.

[DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1KrO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @kevin hutin i think i can help you with it